# filter certain (sub) keys from a JSON value

Tags: json, jq

I have a relatively huge JSON file that contains lot of data that I do not need.

I would like to just keep the elements that are of interest for me but I want to keep the general structure.

```
[
  {
    "name"  : "foo",
    "age"   : 12,
    "weight": 23, 
    "colors": {
      "head":{
        "hair": "blue",
        "eyes": "green"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name"  : "bar",
    "age"   : 42,
    "weight": 54, 
    "colors": {
      "head":{
        "hair": "blue",
        "eyes": "blue"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name"  : "baz",
    "age"   : 65,
    "weight": 439, 
    "colors": {
      "head":{
        "hair": "green",
        "eyes": "red"
      }
    }
  }

]
```

The output should look like:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "colors": {
    "head": {
      "eyes": "green"
    }
  }
}
{
  "name": "bar",
  "colors": {
    "head": {
      "eyes": "blue"
    }
  }
}
{
  "name": "baz",
  "colors": {
    "head": {
      "eyes": "red"
    }
  }
}
```

My actual input object has ~100 leaf keys per top level object and I need ~10 and nearly all on different levels of the hierarchy.

I looked into some json processing APIs (e.g. javascript, lodash, and jq) and could not find such a mechanism. They mostly rely on creating new objects in plain syntax that require to construct the object from scratch.

Like:

```
jq '[.[]| {name: .name, colors:{head:{eyes: .colors.head.eyes}}}]'
```

with deep hierarchies this is a bit messy.

Did I miss something that either allows easier specifying deep objects keys like:

```
.[] | {name: .name, colors.head.eyes = .colors.head.eyes}
```

or some even more convenient: some sub key filter mechanism like

```
.[] | filteKeys(["name", "colors.head.eyes"])
```

I would prefer some command line able program, so I tried with JQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*some sub key filter mechanism* can be implemented as follows.

```
def pick(paths):
  . as $in
  | reduce path(paths) as $path (null;
    setpath($path; $in | getpath($path))
  );
```

And you can use it like:

```
.[] | pick(.name, .colors.head.eyes)
```

<sup>[demo at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/cXw8yBAB7S)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

There are plenty libraries out there. We really like [object-fields](https://github.com/blackflux/object-fields#readme) (build on top of [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan), so it's fast). It's especially great if you want to support the fields parameter syntax. Anyways, here is how you could answer your question

```js
// const objectFields = require('object-fields');

const input = [{ name: 'foo', age: 12, weight: 23, colors: { head: { hair: 'blue', eyes: 'green' } } }, { name: 'bar', age: 42, weight: 54, colors: { head: { hair: 'blue', eyes: 'blue' } } }, { name: 'baz', age: 65, weight: 439, colors: { head: { hair: 'green', eyes: 'red' } } }];

const retain = objectFields.Retainer(['name', 'colors.head.eyes']);
retain(input);
console.log(input);
// => [ { name: 'foo', colors: { head: { eyes: 'green' } } }, { name: 'bar', colors: { head: { eyes: 'blue' } } }, { name: 'baz', colors: { head: { eyes: 'red' } } } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-fields@2.0.19"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-fields](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-fields)